# Render a sqaure in LWGL

Tags: java, rendering

I am making a game using LWGL and when I wanted to render a square it failed. I have reverted back to a working version but, I still need to load a square. All the tutorials I watch are to new or do it a different way than me. For example, they a the Window class as their window while I use a long. Can someone help me render a square with LWGL stable build 13?

Comment: Since you said you use a long do you work with GLFW?
And also `stable build 13`. Do you mean LWJGL 3.2.3 build 13?
What OpenGL version are you using?
Core or compatibility profile?

Comment: Duni I have no clue what core profile and compatibility profile, but yes I use LWJGL stable build 13.

Comment: Then can you show us the code you tried? Just the relevant parts(creation of window, GL context, loading(if your app loads anything), and drawing)